# System() parameters C

Tags: c, shell, unix, command, system

I've a problem with the `system()` function.

I want to create a little program which run a command *x* times.

The following code is to launch a command :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char command[100];
    strcpy(command, "(time lance REF_CLIENT_FOUR002542_C FE-ERPCP-REF_CLIENT_FOUR.zip F > result.txt) 2> time.txt");
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

My command is working when I write it directly in my shell, but when I use this program I get this error:

> ```
> ./lance: [[: introuvable
> ./lance: [[: introuvable
> ./lance: [[: introuvable
> ./lance: [[: introuvable
> ./lance: erreur de syntaxe ligne 34: `(' inattendue
> ```

This error means:

> ./lance: `[[`: not found
>   ./lance: syntax error at line 34 : '`(`' unexpected

I guess that system try to execute my command like `time ./lance ...`, but I want to run this like a command not a program so time lance ...

I've already tried to run this program without the loop, still the same.

I've also tried a simpler command like `ls -l`; that's working.

If anyone can help me, I'll be very thankful!

Edit : My purpose is to run a script many time to have data about execution's time, that's why I wrote this program.

Edit2: This is a part of my script "lance" :

```
if [[ $# -ne 3 ]] # 1st not found
 then
   echo "bla"
   exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -f ${1} ]] # 2nd not found
then
   echo "bla"
   exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -f ${2} ]] # 3rd not found
then
  echo "bla"
  exit 1
fi

if [[ "${3}" != "F" &&  "${3}" != "Z" ]] #4th not found
then
   echo "bla"
   exit 1
fi

if [[ -d TRAVAIL ]] # This is the line 34
then
  mv TRAVAIL TRAVAIL_$(date +%d%m%y%H%M%S)
fi
```

Edit3 : Thanks for alk who help me to find what was wrong is my code, I've added #!/bin/bash in the 1st line of my script and now it's working.

Comment: What happens if you type `(time lance REF_CLIENT_FOUR002542_C FE-ERPCP-REF_CLIENT_FOUR.zip F > result.txt) 2> time.txt` from the command line ?

Comment: Implementing your use-case in C seems a little bit like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. You want to have a look at some basic shell scripting.

Comment: Have you tried running your command the way that `system()` does?  I.e. `/bin/sh -c "(time lance ...)"` - that may expose some assumptions you've made about `$SHELL`.

Comment: If you're using `system()`, you don't need `fork().` The `system()` function essentially does a `fork` for you.

Comment: "*but I want to run this like a command not a program so time lance ...*" please excuse but I somewhat do under understand what you want to express.

Comment: @alk The purpose of my program is to run my shell script (lance) many time to record the execution's time to optimize the script (lance). Sorry for my english i want to say that I think the error could be that system try to execute a program "./lance" but it's a shell script so just "lance" is enough. I'm not sure about that just a guess.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, If I type the command from the command line it's working

Comment: `./lance` refers to the file `lance` in the current directory. The current directory can always be referred from out of itself via `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ./lance: syntax error at line 34 : '(' unexpected

In script `lance` on line 34 there is an unexpected `(` character.

To debug the script put this

```
set -x
```

as first statement into the script.

Comment: I've updated my code. The thing that I don't understand is when I run the script directly on the line command it's working but not with my program. I've use your tips to debug and every ./lance not found is during if at the beginning (I add this part of code in the first post)

Comment: @ArthurDessez: The error `./lance: [[: introuvable` does not mean "*lance not found*", but in file `./lance` some `[[` was "*not found*".

Comment: @ArthurDessez: Make sure your script defines which shell it needs to run in.  If you want the script to run using bash, put this `#!/bin/bash` as 1st line in the script. `system()` uses `/bin/sh`, the login you might run your test from perhaps uses a different one. Also you want to check if `/bin/sh` is a link, and to what.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `fork()` when using `system()`! The latter is a much more high-level call, it will fork a shell and ask that to run the command.

Comment: Without forking the program behaves differently, as the calls to `system()` would run in sequence, not in parallel.

Comment: @ArthurDessez: "*I removed fork()*" So you also want to remove the wait()` as it most likely does not do what you expect. Please RTFM here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html